# How Youtube Video Rating is computed?

Tags: video, youtube-api, rating, youtube-data-api

I'm using API Youtube V3 and i would like to search my most popular videos.
I'm ordering the result by "rating" but the results are not good.

The returned videos have many likes and dislikes but don't seem to be rated.

I would have thought that the rating was a kind of ratio between likes and dislikes but it doesn't look like this.

Does anyone know how the rating is computed or why the API returns no rating for my videos ?

Here is my call with Java API :

```
Youtube youtube = new Youtube.Builder(...).build();
YouTube.Search.List listquery = youtube.search().list("id");

listquery.setKey("myDeveloperKey");     
listquery.setChannelId("myChannelId");
listquery.setOrder("rating");
listquery.setMaxResults(50);
listquery.setType("video");

SearchListResponse searchResponse = listquery.execute();
```

Comment: what does your call look like?

Comment: @johnh10 : Call added in the question.

Answer (score 0):

i'm working in youtube api too. if u r using JSON, you can retrieve like, dislike and viewed no. by calling following url... put id of your video and your google(youtube key).
   https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=p1wMPFvRk34&key=YourKey&part=snippet,contentDetails,statistics,status

Comment: Sure, i could retrieve all the videos and compute myself a rating based on likes and dislikes but it's not what i want. The main reason is that we have 1900+ videos so it would be too complicated and it should be the API's job ;). Thanks anyway for your answer.